# Why spring boot validation doen't work on controllers(@Size - annotation)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

There is spring boot application with java11
So, I have controller

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/user",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class UserController extends AbstractJsonController {
    private final UserService service;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity add(@Valid @RequestBody Users dto) throws Exception {
        Users result = service.add(dto);
        return new ResponseEntity(result, null, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

and my dto

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@JsonPropertyOrder({"users", "error"})
public class UsersDto {
    @JsonProperty("users")
    public List<User> users;
    @JsonProperty("error")
    public String error;

    public Users(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}



import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.List;


@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    @Max(10)
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;
}
```

so, when I am using spring boot starter validation - validation for length field name - doesn't work!
I tried to mark dto class like @Validated and it doesn't help for me.

To solve this problem, I marks users field in Users dto like @Valid and it started to validate, but I think this is bad practice..

How to fix this problem by correct way and why this problem is occours?

ps the way when validation started work

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@JsonPropertyOrder({"users", "error"})
@Validated
public class UsersDto {
    @Valid
    @JsonProperty("users")
    public List<User> users;
    @JsonProperty("error")
    public String error;

    public Users(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding `@Valid` to the list of users in your `UsersDto` is exactly what you need to do. That is how you validate nested object / collection of objects in your objects (that is the way the Java Validation API works. So what you think is a bad way is **the** way to make it work.

Comment: Please make controller `@Validated`

Comment: @silentsudo tried to add ```@Validated``` to controller but it doesn't work

Comment: @Roberto Why do you think this is a bad practice?This is the way to make it work.